# Basic MVC: If-else logic in cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I am just learning MVC and I've created a form but I would like to set conditional formatting ... like with an if-else construct.  I know this is basic, but can I put it on the form?  If so, how do I code that?  What I would like to do is gray out the background of a input box if the checkbox is NOT checked.  Thanks in advance

```
<div class="left">
      Emulate Access
    </div>
    <div class="right">
     <input type="checkbox" name="Emulate" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear" />
    <div class="left">
      Emulate Associate:
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="text" name="NmAssoc" />
    </div>
```

Comment: would you want it to change based on user interaction on the client-side.  If so, I'd do this with JS/CSS

Comment: Yes, can I put a script block inside my cshtml page?

Comment: definitely. or in the Layout page (similar to an ASP.NET Web Forms 'masterpage')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use JQuery http://jquery.com/. It works great for this sort of thing.